# How exactly do asynchronous/synchronous operations works

Tags: java, io, nio

Lets say we have a method `HarryIsLarry()`:

```
public void HarryIsLarry() { 
write("Hello");
System.out.println("Write operation complete");
}
```

Now lets assume that this method is part of an networking framework where write() will send a string to a remote node. Lets assume that write() is an synchronous (IO) operation. Would this mean that the thread executing the task will stop, meaning that System.out.println() will not be executed until write() will be completed?

And next lets assume that our method is part of an asynchronous (NIO) framework thus in this new scenario write would be non-blocking. Would this mean that System.out.println() would be executed even if write() has not completed? Could it even be that the method has returned but the write operation has not yet completed?

Comment: Kinda.  The `write()` always "completes" in that the method finishes and returns to the next line.  What happens with the network is up to the spec of the write method.  Realistically, *any* network operation is going to be relatively slow, so at best the actual act of putting a packet on the wire is happening at the same time as the `println()`.  At worst, the `write()` completed by filling a buffer with data but did nothing else, and there won't be a packet until a `flush()` or some other method fills the buffer.

Comment: So what your saying is that in an asynchronous write() operation the TCP data would be traveling through the "cable" to it's endpoint destination and it might not even arrive at it's destination if were at println() or even when the method has fully returned? Also if this were the case, would an synchronous write() operation then block the current thread(e.g. println() would NOT be printed until the message has been received at it's endpoint destination)

Comment: No, I'm saying both the synchronous and the asynchronous writes might still be traveling down the cable as the `println()` runs.  Or both may not arrive at their destination even though the `println` runs.  I'm also saying both may be cached in a buffer and not sent at all until `flush()` is called.  An implementation *could* block a synchronous write until the entire packet is out on the wire, or until a ACK is received, but I don't think either behavior is guaranteed.  (Actually now I'm somewhat curious myself, my default is "expect nothing," so that how I write my code.)

Comment: "expect nothing," Yeah im pretty sure that is going to be helpfull.